# Authorization header is not sending when using Swagger documentation on drf-spectacular

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

I'm using drf-spectacular to document and test my endpoint. My code look like this:

```
@extend_schema(
    parameters=[
        OpenApiParameter(name='Authorization', description='Authorization token', required=True, type=str, location=OpenApiParameter.HEADER),
        OpenApiParameter(name='my-key1', description='My key 1 info', required=True, type=str, location=OpenApiParameter.HEADER),
        OpenApiParameter(name='my-key2', description='My key 2 info', required=True, type=str, location=OpenApiParameter.HEADER),
    ],
    description='Info about the endpoint',
    responses={
        200: inline_serializer(
                name='Successfull response',
                fields={
                    "result_code": serializers.IntegerField(default=200),
                    "result_description": serializers.CharField(default="Transaccion Exitosa"),
                    "data": DocumentSerializer(many=True),
                }
            ),                         
    },
)
@api_view(["GET"])
def my_endpoint_function(request):
    pass
```

As you can see I'm declaring 3 headers parameters, `Authorization`, `my-key1` and `my-key2`.
But when I try to use the Swagger documentation only `my-key1` and `my-key2` are sending. Here's an example:

[image]

As you can see in the Swagger documentation I'm sending the three headers I mentioned above, but in the curl only two of them are sending.
Does anyone know how to fix this? I need to test my endpoints in the documentation.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you have the "Authorize" button in the upper right which lets you set this header?  It should automatically generate that header for the authentication_classes you have in your REST_FRAMEWORK configuration.

Comment: Do you care to follow up on the answer, comment if it works and accept it if its correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the "Authorize" button that is at the top right of the screen, above all the endpoints.  This will set the `Authorization` header and save it for all future requests.

About the `Authorize` feature:

- More than one option can be present (jwt, basic, etc)
- Any class you use in a `View.authentication_classes` will show up
- You may have to put in the `JWT` or `Bearer` prefix in the value manually, so watch out for that.

If you have custom authentication (or from a package that spectacular doesn't support  yet, like `knox`) you'll need to add an adapter manually as [documented in the customization section](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html#specify-authentication-with-openapiauthenticationextension).  You can import your overrides in one of your [`App.ready`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready) functions.

> ```
> class MyAuthenticationScheme(OpenApiAuthenticationExtension):
>     target_class = 'my_app.MyAuthentication'  # full import path OR class ref
>     name = 'MyAuthentication'  # name used in the schema
>
>     def get_security_definition(self, auto_schema):
>         return {
>             'type': 'apiKey',
>             'in': 'header',
>             'name': 'api_key',
>         }
> ```

This screenshot contains both a custom integration, as well as the built-in `BasicAuthentication`.  If you are doing a custom token based scheme I would say to copy one of the base extentions and modify.

[image: Authorize Button]

[image: Available Authorizers]

Comment: Where should I put the MyAuthenticationScheme class? I created it in a file called schema.py at my project level folder (in the same folder as settings.py). But I does not work.

Comment: Sorry, deleted that comment.  The way I do it is put it inside one of my apps, and then in my apps.py I add, in the `ready` function, a `from . import schema`.   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready

Comment: You could probably put it somewhere else, as long as it get imported.  I think its best if its in a place that only gets imported once, ever.  Adding it as an import in your `apps.py  App.ready()` function ensures that is true, the same as a model signal.